# Fedora RiscV64：the following error when switching the gcc version from 13 to 12

Tags: ld

1. When I use dnf on the command line for update or install, the following error message will appear.

```
[fedora@fedora-riscv libdnf]$ sudo dnf upgrade --refresh -y
  ...
ImportError: /usr/local/gcc-12.2.0/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by /usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/libdnf/_common_types.so)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.